# How to combine data with same rownames to one column in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to move a large list with >200000 character from this:

```
startTime  1
max        3
min        1        
EndTime    2
avg        2     
startTime  2
max       ..
min       ..
EndTime   ..
avg       ..
..
```

to a dataframe like this:

```
startTime  max  min  EndTime  avg  
1          3    1    2        2
2          ..   ..   ..       ..
```

I managed it by looping it through a for-loop. It takes to much time. Is there a more sufficient way by not looping it through a for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding your input data a bit you could use `unstack` from `base R`.

Input:

```
dat
#          V1 V2
#1  startTime  1
#2        max  3
#3        min  1
#4    EndTime  2
#5        avg  2
#6  startTime  2
#7        max  3
#8        min  4
#9    EndTime  5
#10       avg  6
```

Result:

```
out <- unstack(dat, V2 ~ V1)
out
#  avg EndTime max min startTime
#1   2       2   3   1         1
#2   6       5   3   4         2
```

If you want the column names in the same order as the they appear in `dat$V1` do

```
out <- out[unique(dat$V1)]
```

**data**

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c("startTime", "max", "min", "EndTime", "avg", 
"startTime", "max", "min", "EndTime", "avg"), V2 = c(1L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

simply tranform it

```
library( data.table )

dt <- data.table::fread(" startTime  1
max        3
                        min        1        
                        EndTime    2
                        avg        2     
                        startTime  2", header = FALSE)

as.data.table( t( dt ) )

#           V1  V2  V3      V4  V5        V6
# 1: startTime max min EndTime avg startTime
# 2:         1   3   1       2   2         2
```

Comment: Have you tried with more observations per unique `startTime`, i.e. `t(rbind(dt, dt))` ?

Comment: I have to admit I thought of `t()` as well. (Not my downvote)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format) so I will answer.

First create a new column `ID` and then use one of the solutions in the duplicate. I will use the solution based on package `reshape2`.

```
pattern <- as.character(df1[1, 1])
ipat <- grep(pattern, df1[[1]])

df1$ID <- rep(seq_along(ipat), nrow(df1)/length(ipat))

library(reshape2)

result <- dcast(df1, ID ~ V1, value.var = "V2")[-1]
#  avg EndTime max min startTime
#1   2       3   4   1         1
#2   1       2   3   2         2
```

Final clean up, put the input dataset `df1` back as it were.

```
df1 <- df1[-ncol(df1)]
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
startTime  1
max        3
min        1        
EndTime    2
avg        2     
startTime  2
max        4
min        2
EndTime    3
avg        1                  
")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives. They do not use any packages.

Assume the input `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.

**1) xtabs** The first line of code converts the first column to character in case it is factor.  We do not need this with the data shown in the Note but it doesn't hurt and might be useful if the column were factor so that it is in a known state.

Then convert the V1 column to a factor having levels in the order that appear so that they don't get rearranged upon output.  Also define nicer names and create a Group number vector which numbers the first group of 5 rows as 1, the second group 2 and so on.

Finally use `xtabs` to create the desired table.  If you prefer a data frame as the output rather than a table then use `as.data.frame(xt)`.

```
DF2 <- transform(DF, V1 = as.character(V1))
DF2 <- transform(DF2, Stat = factor(V1, levels = V1[1:5]), 
  Value = V2,
  Group = cumsum(V1== "startTime"))
xt <- xtabs(Value ~ Group + Stat, DF2)
xt
```

giving:

```
     Stat
Group startTime max min EndTime avg
    1         1   3   1       2   2
    2         2   4   1       3   2
```

**2) matrix** Even shorter is this one-liner.  It gives a matrix.  Use `as.data.frame(m)` if you want a data frame.

```
m <- matrix(DF$V2,, 5, byrow = TRUE, list(NULL, DF$V1[1:5]))
m
```

giving:

```
     startTime max min EndTime avg
[1,]         1   3   1       2   2
[2,]         2   4   1       3   2
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form. I have added a few rows.

```
Lines <- "
startTime  1
max        3
min        1        
EndTime    2
avg        2     
startTime  2
max        4
min        1
EndTime    3
avg        2"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` solution using @markus' data would be :

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
  group_by(tmp = cumsum(V1=="startTime"))  %>%
  spread(V1,V2) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-tmp)

# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#     avg EndTime   max   min startTime
#   <int>   <int> <int> <int>     <int>
# 1     2       2     3     1         1
# 2     6       5     3     4         2
```